# Wish to populate multiple columns with specific values if matches one columns value in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where, whenever a specific value is displayed in a specific column, to populate appropriate columns with a value of choice:

**Data**

```
id     start    stat
d_in        
d_in        
hello       
hi
```

**Desired**

```
id     start    stat
d_in   din      8
d_in   din      8
hello       
hi
```

Whenever we see the value 'd_in' in the ['id'] column, we will populate column ['start'] with
'din' and column ['stat'] with the number 8

**Doing**

```
I believe I can perform a dictionary mapping on this dataset:




out= {
    'd_in': din, 8
    
}
```

I am not sure how to integrate this logic. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['id'].eq('d_in'), ['start', 'stat']] = ['din', 8]
```